# Start X and Unity from the console

Tags: 11.10, command-line, xorg, lightdm

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and I'm wondering if it is possible to start X and Unity from the console without using LightDM or any other display managers. I use Unity 2D and my ~/.xsession is as follows -

```
exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d
```

Unity starts without issue when running startx, the only problem is that when maximised the window menu remains along with the global menu. With any combination of the ck-launch-session and dbus-launch commands, as well as removing one or both of them (and the dbus-launch arguments), I still experience the same issue. Using the default Unity configuration (i.e. 3D), explicitly setting a shell or using the --sh-syntax option don't make any difference to the problem.

I've tried a variety of different suggestions and Googled until my fingers fall off, it doesn't seem to be something which many people are asking about but for my curiosity I'd be interested to know where I'm going wrong. I appreciate that the dependency tree and things which LightDM manages are vast but if anybody could shed any light on this it'd be appreciated.

Similar sort of questions which don't offer working answers are -

[How to start X and Unity, without gdm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41809/how-to-start-x-and-unity-without-gdm)

[Policykit is not initialised in custom xsession launched via LightDM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63977/policykit-is-not-initialised-in-custom-xsession-launched-via-lightdm)

Thanks in advance for the assistance,

Nathan

Comment: Hi Nathan.  Is the question "how to run Unity without a display manager?" (I thought initially you were asking how to run Unity with another display manager, e.g gdm).  If so it seems "How to start X and Unity, without gdm?" is a duplicate of this.

Comment: Hi Robert,

Thanks for your comment. I've adjusted the title of my question to avoid ambiguity as my question is the same as the one referenced in my post and by yourself. I would like to know if it is possible to start X and Unity from the console - I posted a new question as I was wondering if the situation might have changed for Ubuntu 11.10 with the introduction of LightDM.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)